# Rails 4: counter shows "0" instead of actual "size" when using counter_cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, caching

I've added `forum_threads_count` and `forum_posts_count` columns to the Forums table. The `forum_threads_count` works just fine. The `forum_posts_count` has been reset to "0" instead of showing all of the forum posts that have been created before I added the counter cache columns. The relationships are: `Forum has_many :forum_threads`, ForumThreads has_many :forum_posts, and `Forum has_many :forum_posts, through: :forum_threads`.

I later found out that I can't use counter_cache with a `has_many through:` relationship. So I wrote some private methods to add `after_create`/`after_destroy` calls to to increment/decrement the counter. The counter works, it's just that it's still not accounting for all of the forum posts that were created before adding these columns to the Forum table. I feel like it's something wrong with how I wrote the migration. Please help and thank you in advance. I appreciate everyone on this site helping people out.

**"...add_counters_to_forums_table.rb"(migration file)**

```
class AddCountersToForumsTableAgain < ActiveRecord::Migration

def self.up
 change_table :forums do |t|
   t.integer :forum_threads_count, :forum_posts_count, default: 0
 end

  Forum.reset_column_information

  Forum.all.pluck(:id).each do |id|
   Forum.reset_counters(id, :forum_posts)
   Forum.reset_counters(id, :forum_threads)
  end
end

 def self.down
  change_table :forums do |t|
   t.remove :forum_threads_count, :forum_posts_count
  end
 end

end
```

**models/forum.rb**

```
class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_many :forum_threads, -> { order ('updated_at DESC') }, dependent: :destroy 

 accepts_nested_attributes_for :forum_threads
 has_many :forum_posts, through: :forum_threads
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :forum_posts

end
```

**models/forum_thread.rb**

```
class ForumThread < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :forum, counter_cache: true
 has_many :forum_posts, dependent: :destroy
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :forum_posts

end
```

**models/forum_post.rb**

```
class ForumPost < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :forum_thread, touch: true
 belongs_to :forum 
 belongs_to :user

  after_create :increment_forum_posts_count
  after_destroy :decrement_forum_posts_count

private

 def increment_forum_posts_count
  Forum.increment_counter( 'forum_posts_count', self.forum_thread.forum.id )
 end

 def decrement_forum_posts_count
  Forum.decrement_counter( 'forum_posts_count', self.forum_thread.forum.id )
 end

end
```

**views/forums/index.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'shared/page_title', title: "Forums" %>
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
<div class="actions">
 <%= link_to "Create New Forum", new_forum_path, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>

    <div class="pull-right">
        <%= form_tag @forum_thread, method: :get do |f| %>
            <%= text_field_tag :q, nil, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Search...' %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>

 # LIST FORUMS WITH THREADS AND POSTS COUNTER CACHE
<div class="list-group">
    <% @forums.each do |forum| %>
            <a href="<%= forum_forum_threads_path(forum.id, @forum_threads) %>" class="list-group-item">                
                <h3><%= forum.title %>
                    <div class="pull-right small">                  
                        <%= pluralize forum.forum_threads.size, 'thread' %> |                           
                        <%= pluralize forum.forum_posts.size, 'post' %>                         
                    </div>
                </h3>               
        </a>            
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

can you provide further information why you can't use counter-caches for a `:through` relationship? looking at the `reset_counter` method, it looks like there is code for handling this case:

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/counter_cache.rb, line 20
def reset_counters(id, *counters)
  object = find(id)
  counters.each do |counter_association|
    has_many_association = _reflect_on_association(counter_association)
    unless has_many_association
      has_many = reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many)
      has_many_association = has_many.find { |association| association.counter_cache_column && association.counter_cache_column.to_sym == counter_association.to_sym }
      counter_association = has_many_association.plural_name if has_many_association
    end
    raise ArgumentError, "'#{self.name}' has no association called '#{counter_association}'" unless has_many_association

    if has_many_association.is_a? ActiveRecord::Reflection::ThroughReflection
      has_many_association = has_many_association.through_reflection
    end

    foreign_key  = has_many_association.foreign_key.to_s
    child_class  = has_many_association.klass
    reflection   = child_class._reflections.values.find { |e| e.belongs_to? && e.foreign_key.to_s == foreign_key && e.options[:counter_cache].present? }
    counter_name = reflection.counter_cache_column

    stmt = unscoped.where(arel_table[primary_key].eq(object.id)).arel.compile_update({
      arel_table[counter_name] => object.send(counter_association).count(:all)
    }, primary_key)
    connection.update stmt
  end
  return true
end
```

so one thing i would try is updating to the latest stable rails version, run `reset_counter` on that column and check again.

history has shown that rails has a lot of subtle issues with counters, it's advisable that you adjust the counts every now and then because they get out of sync (ie by people deleting records from the db manually).

Comment: I'm still fairly new to rails. I'm using Rails 4.2.1. How would I go about downloading the latest stable version? Also, I followed [this tutorial](http://www.eyupatis.com/rails-has-many-through-association-with-counter-cache-argument/) and the forum_posts_count returned the number of forum_threads instead of forum_posts. @phoet

Answer (score 0):

Had to write another migration to handle the counter itself.

```
class CacheForumForumPostsCount < ActiveRecord::Migration

def up
  Forum.find_each do |forum|
    forum_threads = ForumThread.where(forum_id: forum.id)
    post_counter = 0
    forum_threads.each do |ft|
        post_counter += ft.forum_posts.size
    end
    forum.update_attributes(forum_posts_count: post_counter)
 end
end

 def down

 end
end
```